# ASP.NET MVC Server-Side Paging (From WCF Service)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, jqgrid

Currently I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and jqGrid with server-side paging. The issue I am facing is that the data source come from a third-party web service and I need to implement server-side paging over the result retrieved from the above-mentioned service. Since I should follow the stateless nature of MVC, I am a bit reluctant to use Session or Cache. Your suggestions is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if your service provider is supporting OData. If yes, then you
   need to look at it and it solves your question on completely
   different way.
2. Cache and Session do not exist in the same context. Session is bound
   to a single user, while Cache is shared for all users. It really
   depends whether the data coming from the web service is unique to
   each user or it is all the same for everyone. If it is the same,
   then cache is optimal as using session in that case would just eat
   your server memory with duplicate data.
3. If your data is not in extremely large amounts, you might even store
   it on client-side by rendering table and then using table2grid
   provided by jqGrid.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let me check with the vendor whether they support OData.